# Exporting a ListView to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ListView that I need to export to an Excel spread sheet. There a bunch of documentation to export GridViews and to a lesser extent ListViews to Excel but not so much in terms of doing some customization before export.

Before exporting I need to prep the data, as a) only a subset of the columns need to be exported b) some of these columns are editable textbox controls.

Doing a simple export without preping the table means that the control gets exported as well which obviously looks really ugly.

At the moment I can iterate the controls and remove the formatting from both the Grid and ListViews thus solving b.

In the GridView and I can just set some the columns I want to hide using Visible = false; and then set back to true when I have finished.

The thing I can't figure is how to do this with the listview.

I am wondering what is the best way to do this as I am kind of stuck.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: I'm not entirely following, so let me start by asking: why are you trying to parse out the `ListView` content, when you can actually export to Excel directly using the source of the data that filled that `ListView` in the first place?

Comment: That is a good question and I toyed between using the ListView or just exporting using the underlying data. I went with the ListView as the data is already parsed into the ListView for manipulation and viewing by the users. It seemed simpler then to just export this listview Rendering the control. This is a web based app and the user gets the regular dialogue "Do you want to open or save foo.xls...".

Answer (score 0):

I actually think this is a dumb question. If I want to export the list view to excel then i'll export all columns removing the unnecessary formatting. Then users can do any customization of the columns in Excel.

To do any customization of the data prior to export then I should use the underlying data types.

The above approach (admittedly my own) is simply bad.